# Passing An Object In Api level 30 android 11 version

Tags: android, parcelable, kotlin-multiplatform

i am trying to pass  data object from one activity to another activity using **parcelable**. it doesn't work in api 30 and android 11 version. i would like to know how can i pass a large size object in android 11. i tried below code. it throws error like

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
> Process: com.example.exoone, PID: 3989
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method
> getParcelableExtra(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Object;
> in class Landroid/content/Intent; or its super classes (declaration of
> 'android.content.Intent' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar)
> at com.example.exoone.PlayerActivity.onCreate(PlayerActivity.kt:20)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7994)
> at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7978)
> at
> android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1309)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3422)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3601)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:85)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
> at
> android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
> at
> android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2066)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

in my main activity file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    val TAG = "MyTag"
    lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    var myArray:ArrayList<MyTestDatas> = ArrayList()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        for (i in 1..20){
            myArray.add(MyTestDatas("title $i","Some Description $i"))
        }
        Log.i(TAG,myArray.toString())
        binding.btnSend.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this,PlayerActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("myData",myArray)
            startActivity(intent)
        }

    }
}
```

in my receiver activity

```
class PlayerActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    val TAG = "secondTag"
    private val viewBinding by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        ActivityPlayerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    }

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(viewBinding.root)
        val getValue = intent.getParcelableExtra("myData",MyTestDatas::class.java)

        Log.i(TAG,getValue.toString())
    }
}
```

in my data class

```
import android.os.Parcel
import android.os.Parcelable

data class MyTestDatas(
    val title:String,
    val description:String
):Parcelable {
    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
        parcel.readString().toString(),
        parcel.readString().toString()
    ) {
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(title)
        parcel.writeString(description)
    }

    override fun describeContents(): Int {
        return 0
    }

    companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<MyTestDatas> {
        override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): MyTestDatas {
            return MyTestDatas(parcel)
        }

        override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<MyTestDatas?> {
            return arrayOfNulls(size)
        }
    }
}
```

could anybody help me passing an object from activity to another activity in android 11?

Comment: Please post the logcat lines in a code block too to preserve the lines and make it readable.

Comment: First of all, the version of `getParcelableExtra` that you're trying to use is only available on Android 13 or later. On earlier versions the function only takes a single parameter (`String name`). But I'm not convinced that you actually have a Parcelable extra. I suspect that `intent.putExtra("myData",myArray)` might save `myArray` as a `Serializable`. Perhaps you should be using `putParcelableArrayListExtra` to store `myArray` in the Intent, and `getParcelableArrayListExtra(String name)` to read it back.

Comment: i am using api 30 and android 11 version. it seems parcelable doesn't work in android 11. what are other ways to pass an object from one activity to another activity in android 11.

Comment: i tested with **intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("myData",myArray)**  and **getParcelableArrayListExtra("myData",MyTestDatas::class.java)**. it still throws the same error.

Comment: You need to call `getParcelableArrayListExtra("myData")`. The method with 2 parameters only exists in API 33 and later.

Comment: How large is this object? You can't pass more than about 1MB as `Intent` "extras".

Comment: Is there any specific reason of implementing the `Parcelable` by own. You can use kotlin parcelize also to do this just by using `@Parcelize` annotation.

Comment: "i would like to know how can i pass a large size object in android 11" -- that is not a good plan on any version of Android. Pass an identifier around that can be used to retrieve a shared copy of the object from a shared repository.

Answer (score 0):

Add this extension function in your project:

```
    inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Intent.parcelable(key: String): T? = when {
  SDK_INT >= 33 -> getParcelableExtra(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getParcelableExtra(key) as? T
}

inline fun <reified T : Parcelable> Bundle.parcelable(key: String): T? = when {
  SDK_INT >= 33 -> getParcelable(key, T::class.java)
  else -> @Suppress("DEPRECATION") getParcelable(key) as? T
}
```

Comment: hi, your code doesn't throw error but it shows null value.

Comment: hii @coppersmith will update the answer soon.

Comment: I have updated the answer. And are you sure that your Parcelable implementation is working fine?

Comment: i tried like this **val getValue =intent.extras?.parcelable<MyTestDatas>("myData")**. it still show null value.

Comment: I understand, are you sure that your parcelable implementation is correct. You can use `kotlin-parcelize` and then just annotate the class by `@parcelize`  no need to implement by your own.

Comment: As you said i used **kotlin-parcelize**. and then annotated with @parcelize. everything is fine, but it still show null value.

Comment: Could you please share the updated code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255865/discussion-between-coppersmith-and-kamal-nayan).